# How to shoot weapon via loop in phaser

Tags: javascript, loops, phaser-framework

I am using phaser weapon plugin and want fire in forEach loop:

```
var weapon = game.add.weapon(10, 'bullet');

enemies.forEachAlive(function(enemy){
 if(enemy.name == 'p1'){
  player.rotation = game.physics.arcade.angleBetween(player, enemy);
  weapon.fireAtSprite(enemy);
 }
});
```

If I have 5 enemies in a row, and only 3 of them have name 'p1', after executing this code, player sprite is rotate to the last enemy, but there is only one bullet.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to everyone!
Now I figured out, that the answer is the fireRate property of the weapon. Set fireRate = 0 and halleluja!